# iOS - Best way to display google map in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, uitableview, gmsmapview

I have my custom tableview cell with google map (GMSMapView) on it. The cell is located on the bottom of table view.
My first approach to display map was to add GMSMapView as a subview of cell. My second approach was to make snapshot of map and add it on cell. But in both cases I had jerky scrolling of table view. The reason of it was map loading. But method startRendering is deprecated now, so I have no possibility to prefetch it.
Is there any opportunities to avoid tableView jerking?

Answer (score 0):

If your table view location is in the bottom, try using it as footerview of your tableview.
I tried it this Way:

func getMapView () {

```
    GMSServices.provideAPIKey("YOUR_API_KEY")

    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: pLatitude!, longitude: pLongitude!, zoom: 10.0)
    let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 250), camera: camera)

    // Using map as footerview
    propertyDetailsTable.tableFooterView = mapView

    // Creates a marker in the center of the map.
    let marker = GMSMarker()
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: pLatitude!, longitude: pLongitude!)
    marker.title = pTitle
    marker.snippet = pCityname
    marker.icon = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "marker_2")
    marker.map = mapView

    mapView.selectedMarker = marker
}
```

Comment: I've removed your API key from your question. Please don't share private API keys on public sites, and make sure you restrict them as per https://developers.google.com/maps/api-key-best-practices#restrict_apikey